# PostreSQL error relation already exists while creating a partition

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I created a partition (programmatically with Java, JPA/native query), after that I deleted it manually pgAdmin with DROP table my_partition. After that, I'm trying to re-create it again programmatically, but I get this error

SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P07
ERROR: relation "partition_2020_12_08" already exists

```
CREATE TABLE "myschema.com".partition_2020_12_08 PARTITION OF "myschema.com".measurement FOR VALUES FROM (1607385600000) TO (1607471999999)
```

Interesting that when I execute that SQL with pgAdmin, it works fine. It looks to me that PostreSQL caches some information when I'm using it with JDBC/Java driver.

How to debug this issue? I need to have a possibility to re-create the same partitions if needed.

Comment: Use CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS. And something else, why don't you use a date or timestamp for your partitions? Imho so much easier to maintain, query and debug.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, it doesn't help: with NOT EXISTS it doesn't create a partition b.c. it think that it exists, but in fact it doesn't exist.

Comment: I suspect there is a bug somehwere in postgresql how it deals with re-created partitions with the same name

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? There is nothing in the above code that looks like a bug in the database. Like you said, it works when you're using pgAdmin. Are you sure you're connected to the same database?

Comment: yes, I'm connected to the same database, and verified that many times. I use java/hibernate nativeQuery, I don't expect hibernate to add something on top in this case, also error comes from postresql.